# JSON-based OAuth authentication via WebAPI - are there any concise templates/examples?

Tags: .net, authentication, web-applications, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a webAPI application that exposes endpoints for html/js clients - all controllers return/accept JSON/XML.  This application has been built and now requires authentication/authorization.

I've found plenty of examples that offer partial solutions but haven't found one simple, recent, concise guide with sample code that shows how one can go from a basic implementation of webAPI to one that authenticates/authorizes both client applications and users via OAuth.

Are there any templates for VS out there that demonstrate this, or any recent articles/posts on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

I can only point you to the wiki for identity server - there are a number of samples for the various OAuth2 flows as well as sample code.

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki